# How to remove top, right, and left borders from Contact Form 7 form?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have one issue that don't know how to resolve. I have Contact Form 7 form, that looks like this:

[image]

and want to remove top, left and right borders from fields, so will look like this:

[image]

So my question is what changes need to do to get that look ? i searched on Google and also Stackoverflow answered questions but not found closer question like mine. This is code that control that part:

```
.cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text,
.cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-number,
.cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-date,
.cf7_custom_style_1 textarea.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-textarea,
.cf7_custom_style_1 select.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-select,
.cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-quiz{
    border-color: #949494;
    border-width: 1px; // Probably something here need to be changed?
    border-style: outset;
    color: #949494;
    font-family: Raleway;
    padding-top: -2px;
    padding-bottom: -2px;
    }
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text,
.cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-number,
.cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-date,
.cf7_custom_style_1 textarea.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-textarea,
.cf7_custom_style_1 select.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-select,
.cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-quiz{
    border: none;
    border-bottom-color: #949494;
    border-bottom-width: 1px; // Probably something here need to be changed?
    border-bottom-style: outset;
    color: #949494;
    font-family: Raleway;
    padding-top: -2px;
    padding-bottom: -2px;
    }
```

This will remove the border except for the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can control each dimension of the box model independently.

```
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you able to rewrite this styles, the better way is to define only bottom border, like this:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: violet;
  border-bottom: 5px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If not, you need to remove unnecessary borders (top, left and right). You can do it like this:

```
border-top: none; 
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
```

Or if it will not work, you have to add `!important` flag to that rules:

```
border-top: none !important; 
border-left: none !important;
border-right: none !important;
```

Small demonstration:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: violet;
  border: 5px black solid;
  border-top: none; 
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```